# Generate report and sort by date

Tags: nunit-console, allure

I am currently looking into the framework [Allure for Nunit/SpecFlow](https://github.com/allure-framework)

**Is it possible** to generate a report for two test runs and then display their timeline - organised by execution date/time?

I have currently run the test three times and create a new test folder for each, then run the generate report on the parent folder.

E.g.

```
 Date/Time-        Test 1   Test 2 
|01/12/2014 13:00 |Pass    | Pass |  
|01/12/2014 13:15 |Fail    | Pass |
```

I understand the current layout is:
*0(Green)3min4(Amber)24min(green)26min30s(red)*

I am planning to run 200 tests, so quick historical checks would be fantastic.

**Is this at all possible?**

Comment: does this have anything to do with specflow?

Comment: I am thinking about using it within a specflow framework, so I'm hoping, it is likely there will be other SpecFlow users who may have used this tool.

Comment: ok, but does SpecFlow have any impact on the question at all? if not then the tag should be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** possible out of the box but you could implement your own adapter version which will produce XML for the first run and then append results to the same XML file during subsequent runs. Allure is just showing what is present in XML. If you have test cases from two runs it will show both. However you need to somehow delimit the same test cases from different runs (e.g. add run date to their names).

We also have an feature request for historical comparison: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/issues/395